# permanent Link to the document through search webservices

Tags: search, rest, document-id

how to get the permanent Link to the document through search webservices?
My site collection has the Document Id feature activated but I don't know how to get this link. I'm guessing I have to set a managed property but I don't know to what... The _dlc_docId solo incluye el docId per se.

Comment: It's always this (SP2010):
http://sp-site/_layouts/docidredir.aspx?id={doc_id}

OR SP2013:
http://sp-site/_layouts/15/docidredir.aspx?id={doc_id}

Comment: Why would you like to have it through `Search WebService`? What is your actual requirement?

Comment: @Boland but when the document is moved to another Site the link remain as the original link? That's my understanding

Comment: No then the link changes. This is going to be fixed in SP2016.

Comment: so how is going to work the permanent link? Do you have some article with this information?